# How can i use the API gateway details basically the environment details inside the lambda function associated with it?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, environment-variables, aws-api-gateway

I want to fetch the environment details inside the lambda function such as stage parameter or api gateway url or http mehtod. My lambda function is executed through API Gateway. need help to find out the correct way to achieve this.

Comment: AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store is a great way to store credentials. You can also store it as secure string and retrieve it within your Lambda function. check this example. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/sharing-secrets-with-aws-lambda-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/